# How would you rewrite this python code efficiently in Assembly

Tags: python, assembly

So as a challenge I'm posting this python code:

```
NIZ1 = 'yxem Nx yzcdxo, am knxfx Vcjs, Gbnnws rx ejnm nj Zxcj'
    SEZNAM1 = 'xfjrmansobyzcdwke'
    SEZNAM2 = 'adegiklmnoprstuvz'

    NIZ2 = ''

        for char in NIZ1:
            if char.islower():
                for e in SEZNAM1:
                    if char == e:
                        NIZ2  += SEZNAM2[SEZNAM1.index(char)]
            else:
                NIZ2 += char

        print(NIZ2)
```

To see if someone can efficiently rewrite it in Assembly.
What the python code basically does is; it goes through NIZ1 and checks If the lowercase letter of the NIZ string is an element of SEZNAM1, replaces it with the uppercase letter of SEZNAM2, which is in the same position as in SEZNAM1.

You can run the python code to see if you get the correct answer.

Comment: This is not a question and thus is not on topic for StackOverflow. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please don't destroy your question. Others in the future won't be able to be helped that way.

Answer (score 3):

Performance is accomplished via algorithms that do less work or spread the load, and sometimes by special features of assembly or some other language.

Still, here you are doing a lot of searching, with nested for loops and once with `.index` inside the inner loop.

With another approach to the algorithm, we can avoid all but the outer loop:

Create a map of input character to output character, so for input of 'a' you output 'x', for 'd' output 'f', etc..  for upper case, punctuation, and all others, the output is the same value as the input.

Then the algorithm becomes:

```
for char in NIZ1
    NIZ2 += map[char]
```

In assembly, or any language, I would make `map` an array.

Next, you need to look at the `+=` operation, which does string appending, which can be very inefficient.  So, we would prefer to preallocate the space for `NIZ2` in advance outside (and before) the loop, and we can do that since we know we will need the same size as for `NIZ1`, the input string.

```
i = 0
for char in NIZ1
    NIZ2[i++] = map[char]             # update 1 char instead of string append
```

Comment: If we know all the substitutions are for lower-case ASCII alphabetical, we can vectorize with two `pshufb` lookups blended together, to cover a 32 char range that includes the non-identity mappings.  (Assuming x86 with SSSE3 or AVX, or NEON has vtbx).  AVX512VBMI with `vpermb` could do it in 1 YMM shuffle, and blend based on a range-check compare.  Actually, AVX512BW could expand to 32x 16-bit elements for `vpermw zmm`, although that's more shuffling, and `vpermw` is slower than `vpermb` on IceLake for some strange reason: 2 uops.  https://www.uops.info/html-instr/VPERMW_ZMM_ZMM_ZMM.html

Comment: @PeterCordes, nice!